# ARM Profiler shows SMLAxy consumes 2 cycles in Cortex-A9. It conflicts with the Technical Reference Manual

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I found that SMLAxy consumes 1 cycle under ARM profiler **ARM1176** (RVDS 4.0).

[**ARM1176**]

http://goo.gl/aS9N0t

But SMLAxy consumes 2 cycles under **Cortex-A9MPx1**.

[**CortexA9**]

http://goo.gl/1kNAoA

It conflicts with the Cortex-A9's Technical Reference Manual:

SMULxy, SMLAxy, SMULWy, SMLAWy: Cycles=1 & Result latency=3

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 3):

ARM has been in the process of deprecating these "simd in gpr" and signal processing gpr instructions for years.  In many armv7 implementations, they are cracked or microcoded or otherwise slow.  In armv8 they are eliminated, and equivalent (or more powerful) NEON instructions are available instead.  It's basically part of the growing pains of modernizing and streamlining the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct. SMLAxy consumes 2 cycles on ARMv7.

However, it's important to know that SMULxy consumes only 1 cycle.

Assuming you raised the ILP by unrolling, it's better to separate SMLAxy into SMULxy and ADD/SUB more than often, because SMULxy can be dual issued only with ALU instructions.

For example :

```
loop
ldmia r0!, {r4,r5}
ldmia r1!, {r6,r7}
subs r3, #4
smlabb r9, r4, r6, r14
smlatt r10, r4, r6, r14
smlabb r11, r5, r7, r14
smlatt r12, r5, r7, r14
stmia r2!, {r9-r12}
bgt loop
```

is significantly slower than :

```
loop
ldmia r0!, {r4,r5}
ldmia r1!, {r6,r7}
subs r3, #4
smulbb r9, r4, r6
smultt r10, r4, r6
smulbb r11, r5, r7
smultt r12, r5, r7
add  r9, r14
add  r10, r14
add  r11, r14
add  r12, r14
stmia r2!, {r9-r12}
bgt loop
```

on CA9 or above.

On CA8 however, you have to hand optimize the latter one due to the lack of out-of-order execution capabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the experience.

Comment: I try to use SMULBB and ADD to replace SMLABB.

But the disassembly shows that SMULBB consumes 2 cycles.
http://goo.gl/26v5tW
Did I miss anything?

Comment: I guess your tools are inaccurate, or it suffers from interlocks.